# How to cd into grep output?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script which basically searches all folders inside a location and I use grep to find the exact folder I want to target.

```
for dir in /root/*; do
    grep "Apples" "${dir}"/*.* || continue
```

While grep successfully finds my target directory, I'm stuck on how I can move the folders I want to move in my target directory. An idea I had was to cd into grep output but that's where I got stuck. Tried some Google results, none helped with my case.

Example grep output: Binary file `/root/ant/containers/secret/Documents/2FD412E0/file.extension matches`

I want to cd into `2FD412E0`and move two folders inside that directory.

Comment: I'm not sure on this (hence comment vs answer) but I think there's a command `dirname` that strips off the filename. So, you might need to further preprocess the grep output line to provide only `/root/.../2FD412E0/file.ext` but calling `dirname` on that should return the `dir` at which point you can `cd`. Possibly.

Comment: You should edit give more of your for loop.  I'm not sure why you are using `grep` instead of `grep -l`.  And wouldn't a `find` command be easier for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people mentioned, `dirname` is the right tool to strip off the file name from the path.

I would use `find` for such kind of task:

```
while read -r file
do
  target_dir=`dirname $file`
  # do something with "$target_dir"
done < <(find /root/ -type f \
  -exec grep "Apples" --files-with-matches {} \;)
```

Consider using `find`'s `-maxdepth` option. See the man page for `find`.

Well, there is actually simpler solution :) I just like to write bash scripts. You might simply use single `find` command like this:

```bash
find /root/ -type f -exec grep Apples {} ';' -exec ls -l {} ';'
```

Note the second `-exec`. It will be executed, if the previous `-exec` command exited with status `0` (success). From the man page:

> `-exec command ;`
>               Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be  arguments  to the  command  until  an argument consisting of `;` is encountered.  The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is  alone,  as in some versions of find.

Replace the `ls -l` command with your stuff.

And if you want to execute `dirname` within the `-exec` command, you may do the following trick:

```
find /root/ -type f -exec grep -q Apples {} ';' \
  -exec sh -c 'cd `dirname $0`; pwd' {} ';'
```

Replace `pwd` with your stuff.

**When `find` is not available**

In the comments you write that `find` is not available on your system. The following solution works without `find`:

```
grep -R --files-with-matches Apples "${dir}" | while read -r file
do
  target_dir=`dirname $file`
  # do something with "$target_dir"
  echo $target_dir
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Although find may do the trick, I wanted to refrain from using it since it doesn't come pre-installed on the system I'm working on.

Comment: @Anthony, I thought `find` was ubiquitous. Then maybe try some scripting language, such as Perl?

Comment: @Anthony, added solution without `find`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I updated the code to grep the specific string inside a file with an extension and it tries to do that, but it stops at the first folder

Comment: @Anthony, you must be following version provided by Kent . The code in my answer doesn't stop at the first folder, I'm sure of that. Note the `-R`  option for `grep`!

Comment: Solved now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

dirname is the key to that:

```
cd $(dirname $(grep "...." ...))
```

will let you enter the directory.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it and keep on getting a 'dirname missing operand' message --

for dir in /root/*; do
    cd $(dirname $(grep "Apples" "${dir}"/*.* || continue)) -------- And it looks like dirname prevents grep from searching through the other folders and just picks up the first one it goes through.